# Wordpress cannot change default size of featured image

Tags: php, wordpress

On my blog I want to add an ability to attach featured images to posts. However those images by default are extremely small (150x150px) also wordpress automatically compress the size of them.

I tried to set a larger size two ways: in settings->media I changed size of thumbnails to 750x550px also in functions.php added this code:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
set_post_thumbnail_size( 750, 550, true );
```

But it change nothing and I still get 150x150px images. How can I fix it?

I use wordpress version 4.9.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wordpress doesn't alter thumbnails of existing images in your media after changing the settings.
You can use this plugin to regenerate thumbnails of your existing images :
[Wordpress Regenerate Thumbnails Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/)